# Controlling markers Deployment.?

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am building an android app in which i have to do tracking of a user from one date/time to another and deploy makers using polylines one by one?
In response from a server i am receiving multiple lat/langs in a list. Now i want to deploy them one by one like a video is being played i know how to add markers i just want to control there deployment.E.g Marker A is deployed after 2 secs marker B should be deployed and joining with marker A with a poly-line and so do markers C,D. etc. How should i be able to achieve that. Timer, Threads? Any help or references,algos, would be great although i have searched such examples i couldn't find it yet.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handler](http://javatechig.com/android/android-handler-example) to perform this task.

I am posting an example for you, I have not run it but I hope It will run successfully:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private List<LatLng> mLatLngs;
private PutMarkerRunnable mRunnable;
private int mNoOfMarkersPlaced = -1;

private void showMarkers(List<LatLng> latLngs) {
    mLatLngs = latLngs;
    mHandler.post(mRunnable);
}

private class PutMarkerRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // write code to add marker 
        map.addMarker();
        mNoOfMarkersPlaced++;
        if (mNoOfMarkersPlaced != mLatLngs.size()) {
            // scheduling next marker to be placed after 3 seconds
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bhawna, But i would really appreciate an example of handler applied on markers deployment.Since i am receiving a larger chunk of data from the server side say 45 pairs of lat/lngs.. How would i apply a handler on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks community.. But i have been finally able to do this through. Mark it correct because this really worked for me!

First we animate our camera using..

```
    CameraPosition cameraPosition =
        new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(0,0))
                .bearing(45)
                .tilt(90)
                .zoom(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                .build();

googleMap.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 
    ANIMATE_SPEEED_TURN,
    new CancelableCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    }
);/**
 * 
 * Callback that highlights the current marker and keeps animating to the next marker, providing a "next marker" is still available.
 * If we've reached the end-marker the animation stops.
 * 
 */
CancelableCallback simpleAnimationCancelableCallback =
    new CancelableCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            if(++currentPt < markers.size()){

                CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                        new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(targetLatLng)
                                .tilt(currentPt<markers.size()-1 ? 90 : 0)
                                //.bearing((float)heading)
                                .zoom(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                                .build();


                googleMap.animateCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), 
                        3000,
                        simpleAnimationCancelableCallback);

                highLightMarker(currentPt);

            }
        }
};
```

A bearing can be calculated between 2 android.location.Location objects. As we’re working with com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng objects here, we first need to convert them into Location objects.

```
private Location convertLatLngToLocation(LatLng latLng) {
    Location location = new Location("someLoc");
    location.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
    location.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);
    return location;
}
```

Once we have 2 Location objects, we can calculate the bearing between the 2. This is what we need to put on the Camera when transitioning to the target (the endLocation).

```
private float bearingBetweenLatLngs(LatLng beginLatLng,LatLng endLatLng) {
    Location beginLocation = convertLatLngToLocation(beginLatLng);
    Location endLocation = convertLatLngToLocation(endLatLng);
    return beginLocation.bearingTo(endLocation);
}
```

We’ll use that number to calculate the coordinates of the intermediate point. Once we have those coordinates, we set our tracking marker to that new position.

```
long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
double t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float)elapsed/ANIMATE_SPEEED);

double lat = t * endLatLng.latitude + (1-t) * beginLatLng.latitude;
double lng = t * endLatLng.longitude + (1-t) * beginLatLng.longitude;

LatLng intermediatePosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
```

trackingMarker.setPosition(intermediatePosition);
We’ll also update our polyline with the new marker position, creating a trailing effect on the polyline.

```
private void updatePolyLine(LatLng latLng) {
    List<LatLng> points = polyLine.getPoints();
    points.add(latLng);
    polyLine.setPoints(points);
}
```